# Generate X random intervals with a given length and max/min

Tags: python

I'm looking for a python function in order to generate X intervals.

Let say I want to generate 4 intervals with a length of 5 comprised between 0 and 300:

```
[1:6]
[0:5]
[245:250]
[146:151]
```

etc.

Thank you for your help, I'm using python3.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and where exactly you got stuck?

Comment: @chippycentra the first and the second intervals are wrong, take care

Comment: Let's say that this isn't a code-writing service and you share the things you tried and how they're not working as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like that

```
import random
nb_interval=4
length=5
limit_low=0
limit_high=300

for x in range(nb_interval):
    number = random.randint(limit_low,limit_high-length)
    print [number, number + length]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is faster and generates a matrix `x` containing the extremes of the desired intervals:

```
import numpy as np
nb_interval=4
length=5
limit_low=0
limit_high=300

x0=np.random.randint(limit_low,limit_high-length,nb_interval)
x=np.transpose([x0, x0+length])
```

if you want also the list if intervals, you can add:

```
interval=[]
for i in x:
    interval.append(range(i[0],i[1]))
```